# How to get firefox to use specific TLS ciphers per page

Tags: apache, google-chrome, firefox, encryption, tls1.2

I have set up a webserver to serve mainly one TLS cipher configuration over all others, except override to a different cipher configuration string only on the home page at index.php

Why isn't firefox 54.0 doing the same expected thing chrome/vivaldi 1.10.867.38 does?
Chrome allows me to load non-home pages with different settings than the home page itself using the apache code below, but the same code produces a cipher overlap error in firefox "SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP"

Chrome:

```
/index.php loads fine with correct specific settings

/* everything else also loads fine with correct DIFFERENT settings
```

Firefox:

```
/index.php error

/* everything else has error
```

neither /index.php or /* try to use different settings it seems like. This is driving me nuts that it works just fine in Chrome but not firefox

Am I missing something?

Perhaps this is renegotiation issue? Which if that's the case, I shouldn't even try to use 2 different cipher strings if I want security against renegotiation attacks? Right?

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443>
    DocumentRoot /htdocs
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite DH+AES256:DH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES256:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:!MD5:!DSS:!SHA:!SHA256:!AES128:!ECDH
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
        SSLCompression Off
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /.key
        SSLCertificateFile /.crt
        SSLCertificateChainFile /chainfile
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown
        CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
            "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    </IfModule>
    <Files "index.php">#this is where I specify a different cipher, and it fails on firefox, doesn't even load when it should
        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:DH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES256:SHA384:SHA256:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXP:!MD5:!DSS:!SHA:!AES128
        </IfModule>
    </Files>
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: I don't know how this is "working" for Chrome, but TLS settings are per-host. You can't configure different TLS settings by path / page name because the server doesn't even know what page is being required until *after* the TLS handshake is complete.

Comment: @vcsjones It works with Vivaldi very strangely, sometimes it wont show the correct configuration though so it's really hit or miss, seems like it works mostly. But I didn't know that wasn't supposed to be normal feature... Extremely strange. Okay so I should definitely choose one cipher config and stick with it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @vcsjones it does seem that that is not a default feature of common browsers, so in other words its not really possible to get consistent results without strange behavior or (potentially even glitches in the programs themselves?)